# How to make violin plots with additional single value points in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a violin plot in ggplot where for each group of data I plot a distribution as a violin plot and a single observed value as a dot, like so:

[image]

Does anyone know how to do that?

Here's an example of the data:

```
p <- data.frame("Experimental_group" = c("Group_1", "Group_1", "Group_1", "Group_1", "Group_1", "Group_1", "Group_1", "Group_2", "Group_2", "Group_2", "Group_2", "Group_2", "Group_2", "Group_2"), "Set" = c("Distribution", "Distribution", "Distribution", "Distribution", "Distribution", "Distribution", "Observed", "Distribution", "Distribution", "Distribution", "Distribution", "Distribution", "Distribution", "Observed"), "Value" = c(18, 20, 17, 13, 29, 18, 180, 14, 23, 11, 26, 24, 10, 200))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ggplot2` you can specify different data for each layer. You can use `filter` from `dplyr` to filter your data for each layer. Filter for distribution in the `geom_violin` layer and add a `geom_point` layer for your single observation.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
  geom_violin(data = p %>% filter(Set == "Distribution"), 
              aes(x = Experimental_group, y = Value, fill = Experimental_group)) + 
  geom_point(data = p %>% filter(Set == "Observed"),
             aes(x = Experimental_group, y = Value, color = Experimental_group), size = 5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach. You can subset your dataframe `p` into `Distribution` and `Observed`. Then you can combine different `geom_*()` elements to add points or text and reach the expected output. This code helps to achieve a result similar to what you want:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Subset data
p1 <- p %>% filter(Set=='Distribution')
p2 <- p %>% filter(Set!='Distribution') %>% mutate(Label='***')
#Plot
ggplot(p1,aes(x=Experimental_group,y=Value,fill=Experimental_group))+
  geom_violin()+
  geom_point(data=p2,aes(x=Experimental_group,y=Value,color=Experimental_group))+
  geom_text(data=p2,aes(x=Experimental_group,y=Value,label=Label),fontface='bold',vjust=-0.25)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- subset(p, Set != "Observed")
p2 <- subset(p, Set == "Observed")

ggplot(p1) +
  aes(x = Experimental_group, y = Value) +
  geom_violin() +
  geom_point(data = p2)
```